# Why is my Bar Chart inverted?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

**CODEPEN:**

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dWXBeZ

---

**QUESTION:**

It seems my D3 Bar Chart data is inversed and the bars do not cover the full height of the chart.

How can I properly scale the bars ?

Something is wrong with my `xScale` and `yScale` I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need to subtract the height *outside* of applying the `yScale`. For example, instead of:

`.attr("y", (d, i) => yScale(h - d[1]))`

`.attr("y", (d, i) => h - yScale(d[1]))`

or rather, in your case with `padding`:

`.attr("y", (d, i) => h - padding - yScale(d[1]))`

Apply the same fix to `text`'s `y` positioning.